# set onclick listener not working in android for moving from one fragment to another activity

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-activity, nullpointerexception

My App gets crashed when I have set intent to go from one fragment to another activity. I have set *onClickListener* on it. and It shows me no error what is the problem. Here is the code for it. Whenever a user clicks on an image he is taken to another activity this is what I am trying to do.

```
    public class HomeFragment extends Fragment  {

     private ImageView images;

     public HomeFragment() {
     // Required empty public constructor
     }
     @Override
     public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                         Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
    images = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.complaint_posted);
      images.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
        Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), DetailPost.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
    return view;
}
```

`
This is my logcat

[image: Logcat]

Comment: Did you register DetailPost in manifest? Please add Logcat

Comment: Write  setOnclick lister of images in onCreateView(), you closed it. just check the braces{} opening and closing

Comment: you probably getting null pointer exception as @Allu said you closed the braces, move your onClickListener inside the brace

Comment: @rookieDeveloper I corrected it and it is still not working. App still gets crashed

Comment: try debug, you can get where it is giving error, or post the exception stacktrace

Comment: Add you fragment_home.xml and manifest.xml

Comment: instead of `getActivity` pass `getContext()` it will do the job

Comment: Can you add fragment_home.xml

Comment: Can you mark the line, which error occurred, HomeFragment.java 62

Comment: Is this ImageView "complaint_posted" exist in your fragment_home?

Answer (score 0):

I will suggest to Override onActivityCreated method :

```
  @Override
 public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
   Bundle savedInstanceState) {

   View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_home, container, false);
  return view;
 }

 @Override
  public void onActivityCreated(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
     super.onActivityCreated(savedInstanceState);
     images = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.complaint_posted);
     images.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
    Intent intent=new Intent(getActivity(), DetailPost.class);
    startActivity(intent);
    }
 });
}
```

I will suggest to try to change your code. It will work

Answer (score -1):

okay, so its actually pretty simple, you just need to change your code

add this line when you declare everything in the beginning,

```
 final Context context = this.getActivity().getApplicationContext();
```

and then change the intent to

```
Intent intent=new Intent(context, DetailPost.class);
```

because when your calling the getActivity(); method your not referring to which activity you are getting.